# Firestore Wildcard Variable Does Not Work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to test Firestore Security Rules using the code I get from [Its Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions). But it doesn't work. Even the auto complete for wildcard variable is not working, the strange things is, it works with "{database}" variable.

Notice in this screenshot that variable `userid` is returning "{userid}", not the id of the user which is "TBfnHh13tCNHmN9aBDhYPNTPsrw1".
[image: variable doesnot work]

Here is the full code:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If i replace the above code with this, it can work. So it seems that the problem is the Wildcard Variable.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == "TBfnHh13tCNHmN9aBDhYPNTPsrw1";
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: I wish I understood this stuff well enough to post this as an answer, but what about `resource.id` as described ("described"? more like mentioned) here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#id.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show your query parameters.  You've scrolled down on the left panel too far.  Please edit the question to state more clearly what your query is.  It would actually be better if you didn't rely on the screenshot and instead copied the values you're using into the question.  Note that the values you provide in the left panel would be the same values you use in your code when you make an actual query.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you! I've found the solution because of the clue you have given. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Doug Stevenson I've found the solution.

Notice in screenshot below that I've write `/users/{userId}` in the Location field, **which is wrong**. I should put an id directly in the field, for example `/users/P41jhUbe2SUkgtNUensmypfs3ff1` and that solved the problem.

[image: location variable]